# How to break down a monolith Grails application?

Tags: java, web-services, grails, refactoring, grails-plugin

We have a **monolith** Grails application. Now, the we are pushing to productize the app and cater it to different branches. I'm not sure what's the proper strategy to do this in Grails 2.4.

I'm thinking of creating a *trunk version first with the core services/functionalities* that can easily be included and excluded as needed by a branch.

1. Should I break the domain, controller, service classes and views into separate plugins? Then add to the branch version the plugin dependency if needed? How to migrate to plugins?
2. If not plugins, how else can I achieve the above goal? (microservices, etc.)
3. Or should I just make the current monolith app as trunk version and then modify it as needed for each branches (no more separating of services) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Branches are not meant for subprojects but different versions.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that you need to break up this application is along the lines of the domain. If you're mixing domains of your product, then that may be best suited for splitting up and putting up boundaries of communication.

A few things:

1. Any time you split up an monolith application into 2 you're going to have to create a shared library of interface classes so that both sides can communicate. (We'll it'll save time) You're going to have to create a second app for this.
2. Branches are not meant to share subprojects. Branches are seperated sections of your root application. For example, per each feature. (That would be an individual branch)